# how to check whether newly entering value is already present in database or not in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to check whether `image_name` already exist or not I have tried something like this, here `image_id` and `image_name` are same

```
@image= MImage.where('image_name= ?',params[:image_name])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do it as,

```
image_present? = MImage.where(image_name: params[:image_name]).present?
```

Mostly [Rails-uniqueness](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness) validation is used in model to add error if attribute already present for another object

Answer (score 1):

Rails (ActiveRecord) has the `exists?` method to do this kind of queries:

```
if MImage.exists?('image_name= ?', params[:image_name])
  # Do something if it exists
else
  # Do something if it doesn't exists
end
```

The links to the docs https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.2/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-exists-3F

Answer (score 0):

You can use MImage.where(image_name:  params[:image_name]).exists? to check it.